# Trying to add a day condition to a snowflake task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to add a day condition to a snowflake task. The limitation is that I need to schedule this task after task A, except on Sundays, when this task shouldn't run at all. Adding the "after task A" mention will not allow me to also mention the days of the week during which my task will run. Is it possible to achieve this task schedule conditional exception ?

Tried to create the condition in the called stored procedure, it works but it's not ideal as the schedules are expected to frequently change, while the stored procedures should remain fixed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK_B
    WAREHOUSE = WRH_L
    USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = 3600000 --1h
    AFTER TASK_A
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_NTZ) <> 0 // This is the line I tried to add but seems I can only call system functions using WHEN
    AS
    CALL SP_A();
```

I've also added another Task TASK_A_NOT_SUNDAY which does nothing, but runs only if the current day is not sunday and added it as a condition in the above task, but i was curious if a better solution exists :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TASK_B
WAREHOUSE = WRH_L
USER_TASK_TIMEOUT_MS = 3600000 --1h
AFTER TASK_A
AFTER TASK_A_NOT_SUNDAY
AS
CALL SP_A();
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us what have you done so far ?

Comment: added the code now, thx!

Comment: Hi if you will not be changing the condition NOT to run on Sunday then one way is to  in the procedure SP_A() , exit out if the day is Sunday, by using the " SELECT DAYNAME(current_date) AS DAY "

Comment: yes, this could work, however i want to still be able to manually launch the procedure if needed, which can happen on a sunday, and in this case it won't work. this is why I was looking for the best way to do it in the task itself rather than changing the procedure

Comment: Just create different parent tasks for Sunday and other days